# or statement invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, a friend of mine told me about or statements but when I use it, it says invalid syntax... but won't tell me where

```
#Fun Game

print("Enter name")

firstname = input()

print ("Thousands of years further from our time, the continents collided, creating mass devastation and heat.You,"+firstname+" lived in a peacful village until")

print (" your village was raided by four men, everyone else died other than you, who was trained as an assasin and killed them all") 

age1 = input ("you,"+firstname+" as a 16 year old killed them all and escaped into a cave. Now that cave is what you call home.Enter your character's current age(max 25 min 20) ")

if age1 == "20":
    print("")

or age1 == "21":
    print("")

or age1 == "22":
    print ("")

or age1 == "23":
    print ("")

or age1 == "24":
    print ("")

or age1 == "25":
    print("")

else:
    print ("Choose an age in the list")

cave1 = input ("You can do 2 things:")

print ("1.Go to your friend's village(700 people,military grade)and trade,look for bountys and find news")
```

Comment: Python always tells you where the error is.

Comment: didn't do it this time (do you know why?)

Comment: Are you running this in IDLE?

Comment: to see if there are mistakes,yes,then I run in CMD

Comment: There probably is an arrow that points to an `or`... Seeing as you want `elif` instead of `or`

Comment: Yup cricket_007 that was the problem

Comment: No need to mark your posts as `[SOLVED]`. That is what the checkmark below is for. Glad you found your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poonam's answer looks fine, but you probably also don't want that many if statements:

```
print("Enter name")

firstname = input()

print ("Thousands of years further from our time, the continents collided, creating mass devastation and heat.You,"+firstname+" lived in a peacful village until")

print (" your village was raided by four men, everyone else died other than you, who was trained as an assasin and killed them all")

age1 = input ("you,"+firstname+" as a 16 year old killed them all and escaped into a cave. Now that cave is what you call home.Enter your character's current age(max 25 min 20) ")

if age1 in ["20","21","22","23","24","25"]:
  print("")
else:
  print ("Choose an age in the list")

cave1 = input ("You can do 2 things:")

print ("1.Go to your friend's village(700 people,military grade)and trade,look for bountys and find news")
```

Comment: Yup that was a fine, answer

Comment: Or somewhat nicer if you actually want to verify it's even an age (`int`), you can check `if 20 <= int(age) <= 25:`, paying the cost of one conversion to reduce the checks from 6 to 2 (though if it wasn't interpretable as an `int`, this would raise an exception; you could catch it or let it dump to the user and end the program).

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Enter name")

firstname = input()

print ("Thousands of years further from our time, the continents collided, creating mass devastation and heat.You,"+firstname+" lived in a peacful village until")

print (" your village was raided by four men, everyone else died other than you, who was trained as an assasin and killed them all")

age1 = input ("you,"+firstname+" as a 16 year old killed them all and escaped into a cave. Now that cave is what you call home.Enter your character's current age(max 25 min 20) ")

if age1 == "20": print("")

elif  age1 == "21": print("")

elif age1 == "22": print ("")

elif age1 == "23": print ("")

elif age1 == "24": print ("")

elif age1 == "25": print("")

else: print ("Choose an age in the list")

cave1 = input ("You can do 2 things:")

print ("1.Go to your friend's village(700 people,military grade)and trade,look for bountys and find news")
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the 'or' operator, you use it as part of the condition.
For example:

```
if x == 1 or x == 5:
    print(x)
```

So your code would be one long line, without all of the print statements:

```
if age1 == "20" or age1 == "21" or age1 == "22" or age1 == "23" or age1 == "24" or age1 == "25":
    print("")
```

From your code I think what you want is an elif statement:

```
if age1 == "20":
    ##Do something based on input of 20
elif age1 == "21":
    ##Do something else if input is 21
elif age1 == "22":
    ##Something else again if input is 22
else:
    ##Do something if the age is not captured above.
```

You only need to use the "or" operator if you need one of two or more conditions to be true. But if you just want to check if the input age is within the range try this:

```
if inval >= 20 and inval <= 25:
    print("Correct Value")
else:
    print("Incorrect value")
```

Or, using range:

```
if inval in range(20, 26):
    print("Correct Value")
else:
    print("Incorrect value")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,Andrew it turns out that's the problem

Comment: I needed the elif statement